# dll process in system?

Tags: dll, loading

i have a doubt in dlls loading &processing in memory ,normally dlls are shared library so dll should loads once is enough.if a process loads a dll (ex.advapi32.dll )into memory means ,after that another process how refers advapi32.dll to that process ...how can share common location for each process...

Comment: DLLs are memory mapped so they are shared, however that is just the loading of the code into memory.  Whether it's a singleton or the code creates unique instances is entirely up to you when you develop the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but yes, if multiple processes import the same DLL, then the read-only sections of that DLL are typically mapped into all of those processes. On the other hand, section that can change, like the BSS (variable) segment, get a copy in each process so that the changes that one process makes are invisible to other processes. If you want certain changes to be shared between processes for your own DLL, you can mark a data section in the DLL as shared. Exactly how you do this depends on the development tools you're using.

Comment: Per Larsen, thanks for ur reply...i got a clear view about shared usage of dlls....